# How do I get the grey area around my HTML button to go away?

Tags: javascript, html, button, font-awesome

I am using font awesome icons in my HTML.

Heres what that looks like

```
  <button type="button" ng-click="authenticate('facebook')"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-5x"></i></button>
```

Here's what the button actually looks like...[image]

I want it to just be the icon.

Is this possible?

Comment: Add `padding : 0px;` to your CSS.

Comment: @Arjun that changes it, but doesn't remove it.

Comment: `changes it` .....????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because every browser add their own CSS rules. You can solve it by removing border, background and padding from the *button* element:

```
button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Also take a look at some css libraries like "normalize.css" or "reset.css" to remove any CSS rules defined by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to re-position the background image and make the button width and height smaller.

**Edit.**

Just had a look into fontawesone and the icons are created using an actual font and not a background image. I would therefore look at Alejandro Rodríguez's answer.